# Method for detecting unintended use of memory on allocated pieces?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, initialization, address-sanitizer

I have a data structure that allocates a contiguous chunk of memory for performance reasons.
But later, there are holes in this memory that will not be used, initialized, or touched.

Since it is very easy to overrun indices at runtime,
in debug mode, at least, I would like to make this memory "inaccessible", i.e., make access to it behave as closely as possible as a segmentation fault.

The way I think about it is that it would be great to allocate and immediately mark parts of that as inaccessible for the rest of the lifetime of that allocated memory.

I read about "memory poisoning" that can be detected by Address Sanitizers.
For example, using `ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION` from https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerManualPoisoning

However, I don't want to add a dependency to the project; it also seems (?) that I need to run and compile with address sanitizers for this.

**What methods can I use to detect unintended use of memory by "marking" it after allocation?**

Initially, I was thinking about a simulated segmentation, but other methods are welcome.

(Something that works, let's say, on Linux, with GCC and clang.)

Comment: Is this about simulating the symptoms/effect of a segfault? Or about detecting poisoned memory (i.e. before the simulated segfault)? I think you should focus your question on one of the two.

Comment: _"Something that works, let's say, on Linux, with GCC and clang"_ - Then just use AddressSanitizer. Even MSVC has included it.

Comment: ASan is testing and debugging tool. Debugging tools are not dependencies of product. Debugging tools do not test nor debug, these help to test and debug. Manufacturing debugging and testing tools is different topic from debugging and testing a product. Performance, reliability and ease of usage of ASan will be difficult to beat so you are in danger of wasting time to manufacture one that makes debugging and testing harder than with ASan.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd avoid the dependency. Wrap it in your own macros to allow it to be added/removed transparently.

Comment: @Yunnosch, yes, the idea is to mark, after allocating pieces of memory that will later give a (simulated) segfault. I thought this was called memory poison, but may be I am wrong.

Comment: So what you are asking is not about simulating a segfault and instead about detecting unintended use of memory. I recommend to [edit] and delete "simulate segfault" from title and body.

Answer (score 1):

> What methods can I use to detect unintended use of memory by "marking" it after allocation?

The memory poisoning is *exactly* what you are looking for.

> However, I don't want to add a dependency to the project; it also seems (?) that I need to run and compile with address sanitizers for this.

The macros provided by the `asan_interface.h` expand into *nothing* when you are compiling without the sanitizers. You can continue to compile and test your code normally, but when you are ready to test it with sanitizers<sup>1</sup>, just add the `-fsanitize=address` to your `CFLAGS` and/or `CXXFLAGS`, and voila -- you've got the extra checking you want.

You can also avoid the dependency of the project on `asan_interface.h` using the same technique:

```
#if __has_feature(address_sanitizer) || defined(__SANITIZE_ADDRESS__)
#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>
#else
#define ASAN_POISON_MEMORY_REGION(addr, size) \
  ((void)(addr), (void)(size))
#define ASAN_UNPOISON_MEMORY_REGION(addr, size) \
  ((void)(addr), (void)(size))
#endif
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Which should ideally be *all the time*, but at least daily.

Comment: Sorry, some comments convinced me to separate the actual goal from the concept of memory poisoning from simulating segfaults. I didn't know that one could guard the inclusion of the header file. That was the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to detect out of bounds memory accesses is to use the operating
system's memory protection facilities to mark memory pages as
inaccessible.  Accesses to those pages will then trigger a memory access
violation ("segmentation fault" in unix-speak).  The main limitation of
this approach is the protection can only be controlled at the page
granularity, typically 4 kiB or 8 kiB.

The [Electric Fence](https://elinux.org/Electric_Fence) tool does this
automatically for all `malloc`ed memory, placing inaccessible guard
pages before and after every allocated block, and making `free`d memory
inaccessible.  However, it's been a very long time since I used it, and
I don't know about its current maintenance status.

To do this directly without any third-party tool, under Linux, we can use
[`mprotect`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) to
make pages inaccessible.  We can use POSIX
[`sysconf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/sysconf.html)
to detect the page size, and use C11
[`aligned_alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc)
to allocate page-aligned data.

Here is a complete example program that allocates four pages, then makes
the pages on either end inaccessible.  The idea is the two middle pages
are meant to be used by the program, while any access to the end pages
will trigger a segfault:

```
// mprotect.c
// Demonstrate using 'mprotect' to make some allocated memory inaccessible.

#include <stdio.h>                     // printf, perror
#include <stdlib.h>                    // aligned_alloc
#include <sys/mman.h>                  // mprotect
#include <unistd.h>                    // sysconf, _SC_PAGESIZE

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Get the system page size, which is the granularity at which
  // 'mprotect' operates.  'sysconf' is a POSIX feature.
  long pageSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
  printf("pageSize: %ld\n", pageSize);

  // Allocate a page-aligned region of four pages.  'aligned_alloc' is a
  // C11 feature.
  char *entireRegion = aligned_alloc(pageSize, pageSize * 4);
  if (!entireRegion) {
    fprintf(stderr, "aligned_alloc failed\n");
    return 2;
  }
  printf("entireRegion: %p\n", entireRegion);

  // Deny access to the first page.  'mprotect' is a Linux feature.
  if (mprotect(entireRegion, pageSize, PROT_NONE) < 0) {
    perror("mprotect #1");
    return 2;
  }

  // Deny access to the last page.
  if (mprotect(entireRegion + pageSize*3, pageSize, PROT_NONE) < 0) {
    perror("mprotect #2");
    return 2;
  }

  // Fully overwrite the two middle pages just to show they remain
  // accessible in the usual way.
  for (char *p = entireRegion + pageSize; p < entireRegion + pageSize*3; ++p) {
    *p = 'x';
  }

  // If called with one argument, try reading the byte just before the
  // middle pages.
  if (argc == 2) {
    char c = entireRegion[pageSize-1];     // Segfaults.
    printf("c: %d\n", (int)c);             // Not reached.
  }

  // If called with two arguments, try reading the byte just after.
  if (argc == 3) {
    char c = entireRegion[pageSize*3];     // Segfaults.
    printf("c: %d\n", (int)c);             // Not reached.
  }

  // Note: To clean up properly, we would need to undo the effect of the
  // 'mprotect' calls and then 'free' the 'entireRegion'.  That is
  // omitted from this demonstration program for brevity.

  printf("done\n");
  return 0;
}

// EOF
```

Sample runs under Linux/x64:

```
$ ./mprotect
pageSize: 4096
entireRegion: 0x56551b83c000
done

$ ./mprotect 1
pageSize: 4096
entireRegion: 0x55aff00cb000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Exit 139           # this is printed by my shell

$ ./mprotect 1 2
pageSize: 4096
entireRegion: 0x556ecf87c000
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Exit 139
```

Running under `gdb` confirms they segfault at the expected
locations.